# How does the SPSite.DoesUserHavePermissions work?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to check if a user has permissions to a particular site collection. The SPSite object has one method that is of interest to me.

```
SPSite.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPReusableAcl acl, SPBasePermissions perms)
```

The [MSDN page on DoesUserHavePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453797%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is useless at best, and leaves more questions than answers.

Does anyone have any experience using the SPSite.DoesUserHavePermissions method ?

Comment: True shout on that documentation

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to elevate permissions to get this method to run.

Next, the first parameter you can get away with passing in an SPUser object, and pass in an item from the SPBasePermissions enumeration.

Comment: And how does SPUser relate to SPReusableAcl? Would be great if you could give an example in form of some code that runs.

Comment: Apologies, I was going off memory - I was thinking of the SPWeb's implementation overload that takes in a username as a string (So you'd pass in SPUser.LoginName and the BasePerms), rather than SPSite.